# composer reletionship to laravel during installation

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm new to laravel and seeking clarification on something please! Is it correct to say laravel package manager is installed from composer package manager during installation of laravel?

=> copmposer global require/laravel installer

*EDIT* => composer 
global require laravel/installer

Comment: You run the laravel installer to setup a project.  Inside the project is a vendor folder.  That's where all the composer packages go.  So, after the initial setup, just use composer.

Comment: Yes, `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: @TalhaF. is right - you don't really need the laravel installer.  Doing it via composer also alows you to target a specific version of laravel... LATEST: `laravel new MyProject` or TARGET: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel PROJECT 5.5.*`

Comment: @TalhaF. Thank you mate!